What symbol is commonly used to denote scaling product in LaTeX
In $1D$, scaling an object by a scalar $s$ produces the same quantity than "multiplying" (making copies). But that's not general in other dimensions. For example scaling a square by $s$, produces $s^2$ "copies", or in other words, scales the square by $s$ to get $s^2 \cdot \text{area}$.
I plan to use $\cdot$ for multiplication: $s \cdot \mathbf{v}$, so, which symbol should I use for scaling? I will use $\sim$ for scaling: $s \sim \mathbf{v}$.
If there is no standard symbol, could you recommend one?

Welcome to TeX.SE., I believed that this is purely based on Math knowledge, so a Math expert like egreg will provide the best suggestion :-D

Welcome. // Usually the syntax is explained, e.g. when a book starts. For scaling I`d omit any multiplication mark: a scalar next to a vector (e.g. typeset bold, with underscore, or vector above it ... all explained beforehand) usually is sufficient. I.e. you need to tell it as a reader from a scalar-product and vrom a vector-product, later ... // Whatever you use, stick to your convention once stated.

Scaling a vector is an operation that doesn't depend on dimension.

@egreg a vector is 1D. The difference is relevant in other dimensions.

@wepajakeg I don't understand what you're saying, sorry.

@egreg For example an area is 2D, and scaling it by r, multiplies his area by r^2. Scaling a Sierpinski triangle by 2, multiplies it by 3.

If you have a vector v and a scalar \lambda in scalars field, simply write \lambda v.

I believe you could simply define in your paper/article that $\sim$ implies scaling in text before using it.
Another solution I can give you could define scaling as an operator $\mathcal{S}$ which as an outcome gives you: $\mathcal{S}(b;x,n)=x^n\cdot b$
where $b$ is the original magnitude (let it be area, volume or something crazier like something six dimensional), $x$ is the scale factor and $n$ is the dimension.
You could also say that scaling a number by a factor $\lambda$ in a dimension $n$ is equivalent to it having the property of satisfying the following homogeneity equation: $\lambda^nf(x)=f(\lambda^n x)$
where $\lambda$ is the scaling factor and $n$ is the dimension.

Do you mean $\lambda^nf(x)=f(\lambda^{-1} x)$ (composing x by x/lambda to "stretch" the function)?

First off, I'm not going to be using latex notation ($$) in the comment, to save myself some time when writing.
I was also wrong whn I wrote it, I should've written that \lambda^nf(x)=f(\lambda x). What I mean is, imagine you have a function, for example, the volume in term of the sides of a cube: V(x)=x^3. A constant, for example, c, is a scaling factor in dimension n if it satisfies that c^nV(x)=V(cx). In this case it holds true for n=3, which it means that it's a scaling factor in 3 dimensions:
V(cx)=c^3x^3; c^3V(x)=c^3x^3; This, in turn implies that c is a scaling factor of dim 3

I asked, because a function is stretched by dividing his parameter by a constant, and contracted by multiplying his parameter. But you meant that passing to it a larger object, should return a larger object. That's kind of like the difference of a function in algebra vs programming.
